# Are there other ways to find local extrema for multivariable functions without the second derivative test?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I've got a problem where I'm being asked to find the extrema for the equation $f(x,y) = \cos (y)e^x$.

Assuming I haven't missed anything, the first derivative with respect to x is identical to the given equation, which equals zero at $y = -\pi/2$ and $y = 3\pi/2$. When I plug those points into the first derivative with respect to $y$: $-\sin (y)e^x$, there is seemingly no way to find a critical point given that neither $-\sin (y)$ nor $e^x$ can be zero.

Is it still possible then, to find any local extrema or is the problem dead?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct: $f$ has no critical points. Indeed, over $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f$ is clearly unbounded (take $y=0,\pi$, $x\to\infty$). Often these problems include a *closed and bounded* domain- maximize $f$ over a rectangle, or a circle, or some such- are you sure it's not one of these problems?

Comment: There was no specified domain, the language of the problem simply asked me to find minimum, maximum, and saddle points for the function.

Comment: Well in that case, RIP